# Showing that $M_n(\mathbb{C})$ is a unital C*-algebra

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

I am trying to show that the set of $n \times n$ complex matrices $M_n(\mathbb{C})$ is a unital C*-algebra. Showing that it is a unital *-algebra is no problem, but I am struggling to show that
$$ \| A^*A \| = \| A \|^2. $$
I am using the norm on $M_n(\mathbb{C})$ defined by the inner product
$$ \langle A, B \rangle = \operatorname{Tr}(A^*B) $$
for all $A, B \in M_n(\mathbb{C})$. That is,
$$ \|A \| = \sqrt{\langle A,A \rangle} = \sqrt{\operatorname{Tr}(A^*A)}. $$
Then
$$ \|A^*A\| = \sqrt{\operatorname{Tr}([A^*A]^*A^*A)} = \sqrt{\operatorname{Tr}(A^*AA^*A)}. $$
But
$$ \|A\|^2 = \operatorname{Tr}(A^*A) = \sqrt{\operatorname{Tr}(A^*A)\operatorname{Tr}(A^*A)}.$$
So I need to show that
$$\operatorname{Tr}(A^*A A^*A) = \operatorname{Tr}(A^*A)\operatorname{Tr}(A^*A).$$
I am aware of the trace property
$$\operatorname{Tr}(A \otimes B) = \operatorname{Tr}(A)\operatorname{Tr}(B).$$
But is $\operatorname{Tr}(A^*A A^*A) = \operatorname{Tr}(A^*A \otimes A^*A)$? The Kronecker product gives $A^*A \otimes A^*A$ as an $n^2 \times n^2$ matrix, whereas $A^*A A^*A$ is an $n \times n$ matrix.

Comment: The norm should be $$\|A\|=\sup\{ \sqrt{\langle Ax,Ax\rangle}\,:\, \langle x,x\rangle \le 1 \}$$

Comment: To supplement Ryszard's comment, the $C^\ast$-identity is simply not true for the norm you are using.

Comment: I think [this link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2223101/a-norm-making-m-na-a-c-algebra-when-a-is-a-c-algebra?rq=1) may help you understand why the norm is unique and how it should be defined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you apply your formula to $A$ diagonal, you are trying to show that
$$
(|a_{11}|^4+\cdots+|a_{nn}|^4)^{1/2}=|a_{11}|^2+\cdots+|a_{nn}|^2,
$$
which is easily seen to fail in most examples.

A C$^*$-algebra has a unique norm, since it is not too hard to see that in any C$^*$-algebra
$$
\|A\|^2=\|A^*A\|=\max\sigma(A^*A).
$$
So the norm you need to use is $$\|A\|=\text{largest singular value}.$$
A more manageable characterization of this norm is that it is the operator norm when you see $A$ as a linear operator on $\mathbb C^n$ with the Euclidean norm. That is
$$
A=\sup\{\|Ax\|:\ x\in\mathbb C^n,\ \|x \|=1\}.
$$